# Jquery - Scroll to Top adjust position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a great FAQ Template from [CodyHouse](https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-faq-template/).. and i want to use the template of my site . but my site has a fixed navbar. which is overlapping the fixed faq template . so all i want is adjust the top position of the faq template.

Here's a screenshot , to more cleared question to guys . thanks

[image]

Comment: where's the screenshot?

Comment: sorry , here's the screenshot > http://i.stack.imgur.com/JS97U.png

Comment: Zial, you using Bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked at your site - here's what you can do.

(1) Move div `.stuck-nav` outside of the `.header-wrapper` div, perhaps just above `.header-wrapper`:

```
<body class="loaded">
    <div id="loader-wrapper">
        <!-- etc -->
    </div>

    <!-- Back to top -->
    <div class="back-to-top"><span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_up"></span></div>
    <!-- /Back to top -->

    <!-- mobile menu -->
    <div class="hidden"></div>

    <div class="stuck-nav">
        <!-- MOVE IT TO HERE -->
    </div><!-- .stuck-nav -->

    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <!-- etc -->
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Then, in the CSS, give `.header-wrapper` a `margin-top`, such as:

```
.header-wrapper {margin-top: 250px;}
```

And that should do it.

Comment: I did Tried this one sir , but the site are mess :( i dont want to touched the theme sir. sorry for that. btw, i acutally customized the main js of the template in codyhouse which i downloaded there. In line 82  i change the value of the margin to 100, and line line 23 ( $('body,html').animate({ 'scrollTop': target.offset().top - 19}, 200);  ) actually it works. but another problem existed. i dont know how to call this but see live action https://originboardshop.com/pages/size-chart

Comment: Why don't you choose [a different template](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) -- this is a great theme, and it takes about 20 minutes to walk through the tutorial. You'll learn a ton, it takes 20 minutes, and it's very modern. See also [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_band.asp), and [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_me.asp). And [here are some more](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp). *Don't do the whole bootstrap tutorial - just do one of these themes, that's all you need*

Comment: oh . blimey . i understand you sir . thank very much for your time . and these tutorials . thanks (y)

Comment: I already fixed this :) thank you for your time everyone (y)
for someone has the same problem like me , and used the faq template of codyhouse . just change the value of "margin= 20"  in line 83, .top - 19 in line 23, and topSection - 20 adn margin - 100 in line 120 . that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it.

Basically, keep a boolean variable to store the position of the header (visible/invisible). The reason for this is to prevent the `.slideUp` and `.slideDown` from firing thousands of times without need.

Use `$(window).scroll()` to keep track of where the scroll is at, and show or hide the navbar as required.

Also, we put a `margin-top` on the first body element (after the nav) to push it down below the nav.

```js
navviz = true, win = $(window), nav = $('nav');

win.scroll(function(){
  pos = win.scrollTop();
  
  if (navviz && pos > 100){
    navviz = false;
    nav.slideUp();
  }else if ( !navviz && pos < 100 ){
    navviz = true;
    nav.slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
html,body{height:2000px;background:palegreen;}
nav{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:40px;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:7px;}

#first_element{margin-top:60px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>Nav Menu goes here</nav>

<h1 id="first_element">A Heading</h1>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>

<h1>Another Heading</h1>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>

<h1>Another Heading</h1>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>

<h1>Another Heading</h1>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>

<h1>Another Heading</h1>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>

<h1>Another Heading</h1>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>

<h1>Another Heading</h1>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>
<p>Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. Lots and lots of information. </p>
```

Comment: i will try these . hope it helps me . thanks
btw , here's the link of my site > https://originboardshop.com/pages/size-chart

Comment: sorry @gibberish , but all i want is to move the top position of the faq template to not overlapped the fixed navbar . i'm not trying to touched the nav menu here :) thanks much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple css,

```
.navbar {margin-bottom:70px;} // set margin-bottom as it fits to your needs
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried but no luck :( btw , i'm not using bootstrap. here's the url of my site > https://originboardshop.com/pages/size-chart